# Compare String with multiple ListView items

Tags: android, string, listview, string-comparison

I am developing a Spam SMS app in which I have different Keywords saved in a db and listview. Now what i want is that when ever a new message comes then the message body is compared with keywords list but here comes a tricky part that i don't want to categorize that new sms as SPAM if single keyword matches rather I wanted that message body should be compared with all of the keywords list and if that message contains maximum 3 or 4 keywords from keywords list then the message is said to be Spam and if only 1 or 2 keywords are used then the message will not be called as Spam.
so i wanted to compare my message body with multiple keywords in keywords list but i dont know how to do that.
Here is my code which checks for single keyword but i want to compare with Multiple please Help

```
if (msglist != null) {
          for (int i1 = 0; i1 < msglist.size(); i1++) {

            String keyword = msglist.get(i1);


            if (msgBody.toUpperCase().contains(keyword.toUpperCase()) && !contactExists(context, msg_from)) {

              keywordPresent = true;
              screenMessage(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate);
              break;
```

where msglist is the list containing keywords and if single keyword matches and also the contact is unknown then it is saved in spam class in method screenMessage
Please Help for comapring with Multiple Keywords

Comment: Do not 'break' your for loop, instead keep a count for each keyword matched.

Comment: can you please write a small code for it? I am beginner so if you please :(

Answer (score 1):

```
int keyWordMatched = 0;    
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < msglist.size(); i1++) {

            String keyword = msglist.get(i1);


            if (msgBody.toUpperCase().contains(keyword.toUpperCase()) && !contactExists(context, msg_from)) {

              keywordPresent = true;
              keyWordMatched++;
              screenMessage(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate);
              //break;
}
```

//check `keyWordMatched` count greater than your requirement then add to spam

Comment: Ok sir lemme try that